# How to reset an index to integer values with Multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

When dealing with single indexed DataFrame, I tend to use `reset_index()` to switch the index back to integer values.

With a Multiindex, it is however dropping completely the level. Resetting to integer values does not work.

```
import pandas as pd
from random import seed, randint
from collections import OrderedDict

p1h = pd.period_range(start='2020-02-01 00:00', end='2020-02-02 00:00', freq='1h', name='p1h')
seed(1)
values1 = [randint(0,10) for p in p1h]
seed(2)
values2 = [randint(0,10) for p in p1h]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Values1' : values1, 'Values2' : values2}, index=p1h)

df2 = df1.stack()
```

Result:

```
df2.head(6)

p1h                      
2020-02-01 00:00  Values1    2
                  Values2    0
2020-02-01 01:00  Values1    9
                  Values2    1
2020-02-01 02:00  Values1    1
                  Values2    1

df2.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).head(6)

p1h
2020-02-01 00:00    2
2020-02-01 00:00    0
2020-02-01 01:00    9
2020-02-01 01:00    1
2020-02-01 02:00    1
2020-02-01 02:00    1
```

What I am looking for is having integer values restarting to 0 at each new group defined by index level 0.

```
                     Values   
Timestamp                      
2020-02-01 00:00  0       2
                  1       0
2020-02-01 01:00  0       9
                  1       1
2020-02-01 02:00  0       1
                  1       1
```

Please, has anyone any idea? Thanks for your help! Bests,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simpliest here is set columns names by `range`, so if use `stack` get counter:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Values1' : values1, 'Values2' : values2}, index=p1h)

df1.columns = range(len(df1.columns))
df2 = df1.stack()
print (df2.head(6))
p1h                
2020-02-01 00:00  0    2
                  1    0
2020-02-01 01:00  0    9
                  1    1
2020-02-01 02:00  0    1
                  1    1
dtype: int64
```

If working with `MultiIndex` one idea is use `rename`:

```
d = {'Values1':0, 'Values2':1}
df2 = df1.stack().rename(d, level=1)
print (df2.head(6))
p1h                
2020-02-01 00:00  0    2
                  1    0
2020-02-01 01:00  0    9
                  1    1
2020-02-01 02:00  0    1
                  1    1
dtype: int64
```

Or assign counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df2 = (df2.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
          .to_frame()
          .set_index(df2.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)[0])

print (df2.head(6))
p1h                
2020-02-01 00:00  0    2
                  1    0
2020-02-01 01:00  0    9
                  1    1
2020-02-01 02:00  0    1
                  1    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, I picked-up the 1st way. Jezrael, do you know you are answering like 60% or more of my questions. You're like my teacher, thanks a lot! ;)